# li with different items

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use javascript to create onclick scroll down with many ul that have different li. Some ul requires scroll down but some dont.

```
<div id="background-container">
  <div id="button-right">
  </div>
  <div id="button-left">
  </div>
  <div id="button-down">
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-leftright-container">
     <ul class="scroll-downtop-container">    <-------cant scroll down
         <li>items</li>
         <li>items</li>
         <li>items</li>
         <li>items</li>
     </ul>
     <ul class="scroll-downtop-container">    <-------want to scroll down
         <li>items</li>
         <li>items</li>
         <li>items</li>
         <li>items</li>
         <li>items</li>
         <li>items</li>
         <li>items</li>
         <li>items</li>
     </ul>
     <ul class="scroll-downtop-container">    <-------cant scroll down
         <li>items</li>
         <li>items</li>
         <li>items</li>
         <li>items</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

current javascript of making that happen is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $item = $('.scroll-leftright-container');
  var currentitem = parseInt ($item.css('width');
  var framewidth = 160;
  var maxright = (currentitem/framewidth - 1)/2;
  var maxleft = 0 - (currentitem/framewidth - 1)/2;
  var countside = 0;
$('div#button-left').click(function(){
  if (countside > maxleft){
       $item.animate({'left' : '+=160px'}, 'fast');
       countside= countside -1
     }
     else{return;}
  });
$('div#button-right').click(function(){
  if (countside > maxright){
       $item.animate({'left' : '-=160px'}, 'fast');
       countside= countside +1
     }
     else{return;}
  });
});
});
```

Currently the onclick left and right works like a charm. However, cant seem to make the scroll down work. I used the    `var listitems = $('.scroll-downtop-container').getElementsByTageName ('li');` and `if {listitems.length > 5......` That did not produce the result i wanted. Is my concept on the right track? What is the best solution?

Thank you for any comment!

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the the [overflow CSS rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow):

```
.scroll-downtop-container {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: If you add a height to the rule and change scroll to auto, it will only show scroll bars for the ones that overflow, instead of all of them. But, adding a height might create other problems.

Comment: Overflow was already implemented but the problem is that when you add the height for the scroll-downtop-container. Adding height makes everything scroll-able even those with short item list.